# Format times to display with 'AM/PM'

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs, time-format

[image: Google Spreadsheet]

Normally, when I enter times in Google spreadsheet as `22:00:00` the display automatically switches to  `10:00 PM`but sometimes it's not converting.

How can I set a common format for times in Google spreadsheet? I need this format: `8:00 PM`.

Comment: I've noticed that google has problems with the formats `a/p` and `am/pm` in exporting as well.  You have to use their date format, not the standard excel one)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Select all ranges that you wish to have this time format and go to Format > Number > More formats to select the one of your choice. (I think the one you want is near the bottom and shows as `3:59 PM`.)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to format a time with `TEXT()` to display with `am/pm` you can use:

```
=TEXT(DateField, "HAM/PM")
```

To get a results like

```
1am
1pm
10pm
12am
```

Use `UPPER()` to make it uppercase.